# Syncronized Methods running faster after using Thread

Tags: java, android, java-threads

I had a problem in Android , with java . The printing process was very slow , so I entered inside the code of print task . I noticed the printer library methods had the `synchronized` keyword . Well , I googled a little and then understood that methods holding this keyword were 50 times slower than unsynchronized methods . Than made this methods run in a new thread and the problem was solved . Does anyone have information on how does the new Thread makes this method run faster . (I have no knowledge in java multithreading , it might be a simple problem). I was already inside `AsyncTask` class

Comment: "I have no knowledge in java multithreading , it might be a simple problem" - Suggest you read this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Comment: “methods holding this keyword were 50 times slower than unsynchronized methods” is nonsense. There can be performance differences, but these depend on too many factors to allow to pull a constant factor of 50 out of nowhere.